# Performance with NOT EXISTS - t-sql query

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, group-by, not-exists

This (modified for simplicity) query is part of a larger query, and joined on date with other selects. However I have pinned this section to be dog slow. Say I have a UserLoginHistory-table that logs each login for a user. For each user I want the date they first logged in. (Later on in the query, I group by LogDate to get how many first-time logins there were each day.)

```
select
    LogDate, --(this value is only date, no time)
    UserId
from
    UserLoginHistory ul
where
    not exists
        (
            select 
                * 
            from 
                UserLoginHistory ulPrevious
            where
                ulPrevious.LogDate < ul.LogDate
                and ul.UserId = ulPrevious.UserId
        )
group by ul.LogDate, ul.UserId
```

Obviously the NOT EXISTS-part is the slow one. But I can't figure out how to replace it by something more efficient doing the same job.

With a small UserLogHistory-count, performance is no problem. It's when I get to around 15 000 it starts getting slow. Maybe I should batch the result for each day into another table, but I'd like to find a better solution to this query as there should be one out there...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: By definition, NOT EXISTS must perform a table scan. The key to tuning it's performance is to make the relation that must be scanned as small as possible, ideally a non-clustered index. Without knowing what indices exist on your table, it is not possible to give more specific advice.

Comment: Under most circumstances this is the best method between `not in` and `left outer join where key is null`: [Aaron Bertrand has tested it](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: Performance questions tend to be very platform-specific, which database are you using: SQL Server or Sybase? And what indexes do you have on the table? 15,000 rows isn't very much, so it seems likely that your indexing may not be optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a row numbering method:

```
select LogDate,UserId from (
    select
       LogDate, 
       UserId
       row_number() over (partition by UserId order by LogDate) as rown
    from
        UserLoginHistory ul
)
where rown = 1
```

Rows for each ID are numbered by LogDate, so the earliest one will always be numbered 1.

*Note: I don't think the `group by` in your original query was necessary--the `not exists` clause should guarantee that you only get unique combinations of UserId and LogDate.*

Comment: Now that did a world of difference.

Answer (score 4):

If these are the only 2 fields you are interested in could you not use a simple aggregate?

```
SELECT  LogDate = MIN(LogDate),
        UserID
FROM    UserLoginHistory
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work for a simple scenario, but I chose the dan1111's answer, as it would be more flexible for me.